# I have a an array

Tags: php

I  have an array :- i am getting this values from the `print_r` function .

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [country] => Austria
            [state] => Salzburg
            [city] => Salzburg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [country] => United States
            [state] => California
            [city] => San Diego County
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [country] => United States
            [state] => California
            [city] => San Francisco City and County
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [country] => United States
            [state] => California
            [city] => Santa Clara County
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [country] => United States
            [state] => Texas
            [city] => Harris County
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [country] => United Kingdom
            [state] => England
            [city] => Greater London
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [country] => China
            [state] => 
            [city] => Hong Kong Island
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Andhra Pradesh
            [city] => Chittoor ,Andhra Pradesh
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Andhra Pradesh
            [city] => Krishna ,Andhra Pradesh
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Andhra Pradesh
            [city] => Visakhapatnam ,Andhra Pradesh
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Assam
            [city] => Kamrup
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Bihar
            [city] => Aurangabad,Bihar
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Goa
            [city] => North Goa
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Jammu and Kashmir
            [city] => Jammu
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Karnataka
            [city] => Bangalore
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Karnataka
            [city] => Chamarajanagar ,Karnataka
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Karnataka
            [city] => Chikkaballapura ,Karnataka
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Karnataka
            [city] => Chikkamagaluru ,Karnataka
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Karnataka
            [city] => Hassan ,Karnataka
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Karnataka
            [city] => Mandya ,Karnataka
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Karnataka
            [city] => Mysuru ,Karnataka
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Karnataka
            [city] => Ramanagara ,Karnataka
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Karnataka
            [city] => Shimoga ,Karnataka
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Karnataka
            [city] => Udupi ,Karnataka
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Karnataka
            [city] => Uttara Kannada
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Kerala
            [city] => Ernakulam
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Kerala
            [city] => Kollam
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Kerala
            [city] => Thiruvananthapuram
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Kerala
            [city] => Wayanad
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Maharashtra
            [city] => Konkan Division
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Maharashtra
            [city] => Pune
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Punjab
            [city] => Amritsar
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Sikkim
            [city] => South Sikkim ,Sikkim
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Sikkim
            [city] => West Sikkim ,Sikkim
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Tamil Nadu
            [city] => Cuddalore ,Tamil Nadu
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Tamil Nadu
            [city] => Dharmapuri ,Tamil Nadu
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Tamil Nadu
            [city] => Dindigul ,Tamil Nadu
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Tamil Nadu
            [city] => Kanchipuram ,Tamil Nadu
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Tamil Nadu
            [city] => Nagapattinam ,Tamil Nadu
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Tamil Nadu
            [city] => The Nilgiris ,Tamil Nadu
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Tamil Nadu
            [city] => Tirunelveli Kattabo
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Tamil Nadu
            [city] => Viluppuram ,Tamil Nadu
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Telangana
            [city] => Hyderabad
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Telangana
            [city] => Rangareddy ,Telangana
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Telangana
            [city] => Telangana
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Telangana
            [city] => Yadadri Bhuvanagiri
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Uttar Pradesh
            [city] => Ghaziabad
        )

    [47] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Uttar Pradesh
            [city] => Meerut
        )

    [48] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => Uttarakhand
            [city] => Uttarakhand
        )

    [49] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => West Bengal
            [city] => Darjeeling
        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => West Bengal
            [city] => Paschim Medinipur
        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [state] => West Bengal
            [city] => West Bengal
        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [country] => Thailand
            [state] => Bangkok
            [city] => Pathum Wan ,Bangkok
        )

    [53] => Array
        (
            [country] => Thailand
            [state] => Bangkok
            [city] => Phasi Charoen ,Bangkok
        )

    [54] => Array
        (
            [country] => Myanmar
            [state] => Yangon
            [city] => Yangon
        )

)
```

Problem is I want to make : below output please help:-

```
{
    "result": "SUCCESS",
    "records": [
                {
                    country : india,
                    states : [
                        {
                            state : karnataka
                            cities : [bangalore,mysore]
                        },
                        {
                            state : Tamilnadu
                            cities : [chennai,coimbutore]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    country : US,
                    states : [
                        {
                            state : ohiao
                            cities : [city 1,city 2]
                        },
                        {
                            state : california
                            cities : [city 1,city 2]
                        }
                    ]
                }
                ]
}
```

I tried loop this.

```
foreach ($returnData as $key => $value) {  
    $actual_response[$value['country']][$value['state']][]=$value['city'];
}
```

Comment: Your `Array` and your response does not match with each other. Please check both and ask your question clearly.

Comment: use jason_encode

Comment: @rm_beginners its json_encode

Comment: @Sami That's probably the intention. He wants to regroup the array.

Comment: Groping all the countries and states and city with respective country tab , and state tab.. please help in this

Comment: change your mysql query by group to separate by country india the result state and cities per country "select * tablename group by country" then apply your jason..

Comment: Sorry for that :- No, This is client requirement not use group by in query it will slow the performace hence i have to it in array ..

Comment: assign as index the column that you need to make it fast by grouping is not slow your query is not complicated. :-)

Comment: `[6] => Array
        (
            [country] => China
            [state] => 
            [city] => Hong Kong Island
        )` Empty state - is it typo?

Comment: Yes there is missing in state for the china no problem with that, may be typo only..

Comment: you try to change your foreach with condition inside :-) if meet the name of the country just continue looping of state and cities then proceed :-) create a two temporary variable holding the name of the country in first loop once done change the value of temporary variable to the next country the next variable is holding the next name of the country :-)

Comment: I tried with this:- if($value['country']=="India" || $value['country']=="United States"){
                if($value['state']=="Karnataka" || $value['state']=="California" || $value['state']=="Andhra Pradesh") {
                    
                    //$array_country[$value['country']][$state_array[""=>$value["state"]]]["cities"][]=$value['city'];
                }
            }

Comment: Some static values for testing

Comment: Can you please send me the logic, in programming structure

Comment: @ajazahmedBepari reset unnecessary indexes http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21fbdd410b2265d4b438a62ccc6b7499d8302bf5

Comment: @splash58  I am very close to your answer just wanted to create sub array in state , please help

Comment: i don't undestand you

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

$returnData = array(array('country'=>'Austria','state' => 'Salzburg','city' => 'Salzburg'),array(
    'country' => 'United States',
    'state' => 'California',
    'city' => 'San Diego County'
),array(
    'country' => 'United States',
    'state' => 'California',
    'city' => 'San Francisco City and County'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'United States',
    'state' => 'California',
    'city' => 'Santa Clara County'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'United States',
    'state' => 'Texas',
    'city' => 'Harris County'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'United Kingdom',
    'state' => 'England',
    'city' => 'Greater London'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'China',
    'state' =>' ',
    'city' => 'Hong Kong Island'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Andhra Pradesh',
    'city' => 'Chittoor ,Andhra Pradesh'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Andhra Pradesh',
    'city' => 'Krishna ,Andhra Pradesh'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Andhra Pradesh',
    'city' => 'Visakhapatnam ,Andhra Pradesh'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Assam',
    'city' => 'Kamrup'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Bihar',
    'city' => 'Aurangabad,Bihar'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Goa',
    'city' => 'North Goa'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Jammu and Kashmir',
    'city' => 'Jammu'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Karnataka',
    'city' => 'Bangalore'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Karnataka',
    'city' => 'Chamarajanagar ,Karnataka'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Karnataka',
    'city' => 'Chikkaballapura ,Karnataka'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Karnataka',
    'city' => 'Chikkamagaluru ,Karnataka'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Karnataka',
    'city' => 'Hassan ,Karnataka'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Karnataka',
    'city' => 'Mandya ,Karnataka'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Karnataka',
    'city' => 'Mysuru ,Karnataka'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Karnataka',
    'city' => 'Ramanagara ,Karnataka'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Karnataka',
    'city' => 'Shimoga ,Karnataka'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Karnataka',
    'city' => 'Udupi ,Karnataka'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Karnataka',
    'city' => 'Uttara Kannada'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Kerala',
    'city' => 'Ernakulam'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Kerala',
    'city' => 'Kollam'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Kerala',
    'city' => 'Thiruvananthapuram'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Kerala',
    'city' => 'Wayanad'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Maharashtra',
    'city' => 'Konkan Division'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Maharashtra',
    'city' => 'Pune'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Punjab',
    'city' => 'Amritsar'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Sikkim',
    'city' => 'South Sikkim ,Sikkim'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Sikkim',
    'city' => 'West Sikkim ,Sikkim'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Tamil Nadu',
    'city' => 'Cuddalore ,Tamil Nadu'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Tamil Nadu',
    'city' => 'Dharmapuri ,Tamil Nadu'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Tamil Nadu',
    'city' => 'Dindigul ,Tamil Nadu'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Tamil Nadu',
    'city' => 'Kanchipuram ,Tamil Nadu'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Tamil Nadu',
    'city' => 'Nagapattinam ,Tamil Nadu'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Tamil Nadu',
    'city' => 'The Nilgiris ,Tamil Nadu'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Tamil Nadu',
    'city' => 'Tirunelveli Kattabo'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Tamil Nadu',
    'city' => 'Viluppuram ,Tamil Nadu'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Telangana',
    'city' => 'Hyderabad'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Telangana',
    'city' => 'Rangareddy ,Telangana'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Telangana',
    'city' => 'Telangana'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Telangana',
    'city' => 'Yadadri Bhuvanagiri'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Uttar Pradesh',
    'city' => 'Ghaziabad'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Uttar Pradesh',
    'city' => 'Meerut'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'Uttarakhand',
    'city' => 'Uttarakhand'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'West Bengal',
    'city' => 'Darjeeling'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'West Bengal',
    'city' => 'Paschim Medinipur'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'India',
    'state' => 'West Bengal',
    'city' => 'West Bengal'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'Thailand',
    'state' => 'Bangkok',
    'city' => 'Pathum Wan ,Bangkok'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'Thailand',
    'state' => 'Bangkok',
    'city' => 'Phasi Charoen ,Bangkok'
),

array
(
    'country' => 'Myanmar',
    'state' => 'Yangon',
    'city' => 'Yangon'
));


$finalArr = [];
$csK = [];
$ssK = [];
foreach($returnData as $rdk => $rdv){
    $csArr = [];
    if(!in_array($rdv['country'],$csK)){
        $csK[] = $rdv['country'];
        $ssK[$rdv['country']][] = $rdv['state'];
        $csArr['country'] = $rdv['country'];
        $csArr['states'][0]['state'] = $rdv['state'];
        $csArr['states'][0]['cities'][0] = $rdv['city'];
        $finalArr[$csArr['country']] = $csArr;

    }
    else{
        if(!in_array($rdv['state'],$ssK[$rdv['country']])){
            $ssK[$rdv['country']][]=$rdv['state'];
            $csArr['state'] = $rdv['state'];
            $csArr['cities'][0] = $rdv['city'];
            array_push($finalArr[$rdv['country']]['states'],$csArr);
        }
        else{
            foreach($finalArr[$rdv['country']]['states'] as $facsk => $facsv){
                if($facsv['state'] == $rdv['state']){
                    $finalArr[$rdv['country']]['states'][$facsk]['cities'][] = $rdv['city'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$finalArr = array_values($finalArr);
echo json_encode(array("result"=>"SUCCESS" ,"records"=>$finalArr) );exit;

?>
```

The code you were writing was not enough to get expected response.

Comment: Almost reach to answer but the thing is that :- states should be an array after that inside states array there will be single state of array then city has to show.. I tried to make an states an array i faild

Comment: @splash58 Almost reach to answer but the thing is that :- states should be an array after that inside states array there will be single state of array then city has to show.. I tried to make an states an array i faild

Comment: {
    "result": "SUCCESS",
    "records": [
       {
        country : country_name,
        states : [
         {
          state : state1
          cities : [city1,city2]
         },
         {
          state : state2
          cities : [city1,city2,city3]
         }
        ]
       },
       {
        country : country_name,
        states : [
         {
          state : state1
          cities : [city 1,city 2]
         },
         {
          state : state2
          cities : [city 1,city 2]
         }
        ]
       }
       ]
}

Comment: See County_array ->states_array->single_state_array->city_array

Comment: can u please share a valid json of your requirement which can be parsed, I will iterate it.

Comment: { "result": "SUCCESS", "records": [ { country : country_name, states : [ { state : state1 cities : [city1,city2] }, { state : state2 cities : [city1,city2,city3] } ] }, { country : country_name, states : [ { state : state1 cities : [city 1,city 2] }, { state : state2 cities : [city 1,city 2] } ] } ] } –

Comment: did u check my json which I shared [here](https://pastebin.com/kYvrcyWj)? if you have checked, can u please tell me the difference.

Comment: Hello @ JotK I checked only thing is that states is array states but under that states single_states array should come in that city has to come.. we are very close to out put

Comment: Hello @ JotK  can you send me the php code please let me verify once

Comment: I have edited my answer, copy it completely and run it.

Comment: check my answer above

Comment: @Sam Would you mind to accept the answer as it helped you?

Comment: it helped me. but only thing is that it is process wise slower. but worked thank you. my code review team tell me that if we have more data then the process is slow . thank you very much. I learned from you. I looking to learn more from you.

Comment: I just answered according to the details given in this question, you should accept this answer. Although you can use frameworks like Yii2 and Laravel. They provide the relational data in one array and your work will be done in single foreach. And dont forget to answer the question if you have more optimised code for this requirement.

Comment: NO, i am using yours code only . thanks you for helping me.

Comment: If you're using my **CODE ONLY**, It means it's useful so why don't you accept it.

Comment: Yes , I am using your code thank you so much... for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this put this code below your array and run.

```
    function nested($item)
{
  if (count($item) > 1)
  {
    $key = array_shift($item);
    return array($key => nested($item));
  }
  else
  {
    return $item;
  }
}

$finalArr = array();

foreach($arr as $data)
{
  $finalArr = array_merge_recursive($finalArr, nested($data));
}


$finalArr = array_values($finalArr);
echo json_encode(array("result"=>"SUCCESS" ,"records"=>$finalArr) );exit;
```

Comment: see the results here... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f0aee3e6748a7a11e4b0d0c5ec41b8a7b2363508